# Python evdev exercise: listing accessible devices

Tags: python-2.7, evdev

16.04 installed with evdev module, Goal: to reproduce the [example in screenshot:](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#listing-accessible-event-devices)

[image]

Screenshot of my attempts:

[image]

The 'IndentationError' error signals what corrective action?  What can be done to reproduce the list of devices on my 16.04 instance?  If you are able to [reproduce the exercise](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#listing-accessible-event-devices) on your box, please indicate this in your response.

EVDEV INSTALL CONFIRMATION:

```
>>> import evdev
>>> device = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event0')
>>> print(device)
device /dev/input/event0, name "Logitech M325", phys "usb-3f980000.usb-1.3:1"
```

UPDATE: Rinzwind has nudged the subject-matter in the right direction (no 'IndentationError'):

```
>>> devices = [evdev.InputDevice(fn) for fn in evdev.list_devices()]
>>> import evdev
>>> devices = [evdev.InputDevice(fn) for fn in evdev.list_devices()]
>>> for device in devices:
...     print(device.fn, device.name, device.phys)
...     print(device.fn, device.name, device.phys)
...
```

Wondering if this observation is relevant to troubleshooting:

```
>>> import evdev
>>> devices = [evdev.InputDevice(fn) for fn in evdev.list_devices()]
>>> for device in devices: ...      print(device.fn, device.name, device.phys) ... 
>>> device = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event3') Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/evdev/device.py", line 129, in
__init__
    fd = os.open(dev, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK) OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/input/event3'
```

Where:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
```

Continuing to seek suggestions and guidance.

Comment: Please do not use images to show code. Use copy/paste; that way we can copy it ourself and the question is searchable.

Answer (score 1):

Python has mandatory indentation.

After a line with a "for" you must indent (4 spaces or a tab). So add them before the "print". Those spaces are there in the 1st image ;)